# Course Scheduling

Tags: algorithm, sorting, greedy, heuristics

There are n different online courses numbered from 0 to n-1. You are given an array courses where courses[i] = [duration_i, lastDay_i] indicate that the ith course should be taken continuously for duration_i days and must be finished before or on lastDay_i.

There is also p - representing number of students.

You will start on the 1st day.

Return the maximum number of courses that students can take and tell who takes what.

This is very similar to the leet code problem Course Scheduling III,
https://leetcode.com/problems/course-schedule-iii/,
the only difference is - we have p students

Comment: Need more clarification of what p does in this question. On what basis is the course assigned to a student?

Comment: p is the number of students. its like https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/activity-selection-problem-with-k-persons/ with only [duration, endtime]